# Result of Integration over ImplicitPlot not as expected

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

---

**Edit 1**:

Issues seem to emerge from within `ImplicitRegion` as well as `Region Plot`.
Using $Surd[y^{2},{3}]$ or avoiding $y^{2/3}$ by using $y^{3}$ will result in a correct result of `Integrate`.  `Area` and `Integrate` seem to return identical results.

In other case both the results of `RegionPlot` or `Integrate[1,Element[{x,y},reg]` of the following `ImplicitRegion` will be **<strike>wrong</strike>**, as verified by last result (In case no mistake was done):

$\text{reg7}=\text{ImplicitRegion}\left[\sin [x]\leq y\leq \cos [x],\left\{\left\{x,0,\frac{3 \pi }{2}\right\},y\right\}\right]
$

The results and double checking them unfold as follows:

$\text{RegionPlot}[\text{reg7}]$
[image]

$\text{Integrate}[1,\{x,y\}\in \text{reg7}]$

$2 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)$

$\int_0^{\frac{3 \pi }{2}}  \text{Abs}[ \cos [x]-\sin [x]]  \, dx$

$2 \left(2 \sqrt{2}-1\right)$

---

***Original Post***:

I am trying to Integrate the area mentioned below using ImplicitRegion function, following [this](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/basic-and-formula-regions/integrate-over-regions.html) resource. This method worked in many other scenario.
The plot was accurate, but the integration returned 1/10 which is not true as is verified by the traditional integration.
I have tried integration over $-1\leq y\leq 0$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$ separately and also using Surd[x,3]^2 but things got much weirder. Can any one give a hint how I can improve or correct this?

$\text{reg}=\text{ImplicitRegion}\left[y\leq x\leq y^{\frac{2}{3}},\{x,\{y,-1,1\}\}\right]$

$\text{RegionPlot}[\text{reg}]$
[image]

$\text{Integrate}[1,y\in \text{reg}]$

$\frac{1}{10}$

$\int_{-1}^1 \left(y^{\frac{2}{3}}-y\right) \, dy$

$\frac{3}{5} \left(1+(-1)^{2/3}\right)$

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: The region between Sin[x] and Cos[x] is `Min[Sin[x], Cos[x]] <= y <= Max[Sin[x], Cos[x]]` instead of `Sin[x] <= y <= Cos[x]`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer.**

The region between Sin[x] and Cos[x] is `Min[Sin[x], Cos[x]] <= y <= Max[Sin[x], Cos[x]]` instead of `Sin[x] <= y <= Cos[x]`

BTW, since $\max(f,g)-\min(f,g)=|f-g|$,that is why your integrate work.

$$ \int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x =\int_a^b \left [ \max(f(x),g(x))-\min(f(x),g(x))\right ]\,\mathrm{d}x$$

The set
$$\{ (x,y)  : \sin(x)\leq y\leq \cos(x) \} $$
is equivalent to
$$\{ (x,y) :  \sin(x) \leq y\; \text{and} \; y\leq \cos(x) \}$$
which implicitly satisfy a another condition say $\sin(x)\leq \cos(x)$

```
regionOne = 
      ImplicitRegion[Sin[x] <= y <= Cos[x], {{x, 0, 3/2 \[Pi]}, y}];
    regionTwo = 
      ImplicitRegion[
       Min[Sin[x], Cos[x]] <= y <= 
        Max[Sin[x], Cos[x]], {{x, 0, 3/2 \[Pi]}, y}];
    {{RegionPlot[regionOne], 
      RegionMeasure[regionone]}, {RegionPlot[regionTwo], 
      RegionMeasure[regionTwo]}}
```

[image]

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Original answer**

```
 reg = ImplicitRegion[y <= x <= CubeRoot[y]^2 && -1 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]
RegionPlot[
 DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.012}]]
    Integrate[1, Element[{x, y}, reg]]
    Integrate[CubeRoot[y]^2 - y, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Or

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[y^3 <= x^3 <= y^2 && -1 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]
Integrate[1, Element[{x, y}, reg]]
```

Comment: Or `Integrate[Surd[y^2, 3] - y, {y, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: @cvgmt RegionPlot would render an incorrect plot in your first option (Same with using Surd[y^2,3] @user64494), even though Integrate result is true, which why I came across it.The second option involves a changing of the formula itself. I am still not able to figure out why I get, either 1/10 instead of 6/5,or a false plot or in other case the formula has to be manipulated.

Comment: @pigeon  It it the render problem of `RegionPlot` instead of `CubeRoot` or `Surd`

Comment: @pigeon you can also do `Area[reg]`

Comment: @flinty Despite seeing this many time, It just never crossed my mind due to the need to figure out how it works. It is just perfect in this scenario! Thanks